# Providing a bound on the field-trace of a specific kind of polynomial to solve the finite-field isomorphism decisional problem

Tags: finite-field

I am currently enrolled in a computer algebra class for engineers, and while I have some background in discrete algebra from a previous course, it's quite limited. I'm seeking assistance with understanding the application of the trace operation in the context of polynomials defined over the field $X = \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(f(x))$, where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$. The base field is based on an uneven prime $p$.

Specifically, I'm attempting to construct a bound of the trace for the polynomial $m + 2r$. Both $m$ and $r$ are polynomials in the defined field $X$. The polynomial $m$ and has coefficients in the set $\{0,1\}$ and $r$ has coefficients in $\{-1,0,1\}$, and both $m$ and $r$ are of order $n-1$. I was advised to refer to a certain paper that introduced the concept. This was the paper by Dipayan Das and Antoine Joux (On the hardness of the finite field isomorphism problem, Available at https://eprint.iacr.org/2022/998).

In addition, we are also working with a special form of $f(x)$, considering a monic irreducible polynomial where the other coefficients are sampled from the $\{-1,0,1\}$ - distribution. Hence, the coefficients $a_{0},\cdots, a_{n-1}$ are sampled from $\{-1,0,1\}$ such that the polynomial is irreducible.

$f(x)=x^n + a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_{1}x + a_{0}$

However, the polynomial used here is assumed to be sparse whereas we are still dealing with the $m$ and $r$ described earlier which are very much not sparse.

For people who are not familiar with this kind of operation. In the context of finite fields, the symbol "Tr()" typically represents the trace function. The trace function in finite fields maps an element of the field to its trace, which is a measure of the sum of its iterated conjugates over the field.

More formally, let's consider an element $ \alpha $ in a finite field $ \mathbb{F}_q $, where $ q $ is a prime power (in this case $p^n$). The trace of $ \alpha $, denoted by $ \text{Tr}(\alpha) $, is defined as the sum of all the conjugates of $ \alpha $ over the base field $ \mathbb{F}_p $, where $ p $ is the characteristic of the field:

$\text{Tr}(\alpha) = \alpha + \alpha^p + \alpha^{p^2} + \cdots + \alpha^{p^{n-1}}$

Here, $ n $ is the degree of the field extension, and the sum consists of all the distinct elements obtained by raising $ \alpha $ to the powers of $ p $ modulo the irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ defining the field extension.

The trace function has several important properties, including linearity and invariance under field automorphisms.

However, despite my efforts, I am struggling to understand how to apply the linearity of the trace operation in this context. My attempted approach was to use the property $\text{Tr}(m+2r) = \text{Tr}(m) + 2\text{Tr}(r)$, but I have been unable to find any resources that relate the trace to the specific coefficients in the polynomials.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance you can provide on this matter.

Thank you.